# Can't access .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, crm, httpd.conf, rhel

I've installed a application on my RHEL 7.x server. During a installation wizard which I reach over a common browser, the application will test some components of the installation. During this "system-checks" I get the error message test on .htaccess file failed.

In the httpd.conf are the permission set :

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/>
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

What confuses me a bit is that the .htaccess file is lost after a restart of httpd. service it always disappears, so it is no longer visible.

`Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)`

Also the Selinux permissions and the permissions inside /var/www/html are correct. I don't know more, please let me know if you need more information.

Best regards,
Nico

Comment: I fail to see how we could help with understanding why files disappear on your system. Especially since you write the question in a generic manner ("a installation wizard"), so without specifying the actual logic you are using.

Comment: Sorry for the for the confusion.

Comment: Actually it is about the fact that a check on my web server into the .htaccess file results in an error.

This is due to the fact that the .htaccess file disappears. I make a new installation of the application on the server -> .htaccess file visible.

If I now restart the service apache - it will disappear.

Comment: Sure, I understood that. So apparently something inside your installation either deletes or moves (hides) that file. But how should we say what might cause that?